# How to use one automatic and one manual dns entry in windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

For many days I've seen DNS issues with the WiFi  network in our hostel. So I wanted to use the Google DNS server. But when I go to office, office DNS should be used otherwise internal sites won't load.

At hostel, I want to use the default and Google DNS also. So, windows will use the Google DNS for the address that won't work with the automatic DNS server.

Also, I want to keep the automatic option to obtain the default DNS address.

Is there a way to achieve this?
1. Obtain DNS automatically
2. And Google DNS address.

Comment: You can use some batch files to set the DNS as appropriate. `netsh interface ip set dns name` and `netsh interface ip add dns name`. See [Configure IP Address and DNS from Command Line](http://tweaks.com/windows/40339/configure-ip-address-and-dns-from-command-line/)

Comment: Have you seen/tried the 'Alternate Configuration' tab in the IPv4 properties yet?  See Windows 7: Alternate IP Address Configuration  - http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.ca/2011/03/windows-7-alternate-ip-address.html